# Event argument not passed to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I added click event listener `onclick` called `DagOpenFlyout` to a `span` element:

```
"<span class=\"btnFlyout\" id=\"btn" + i + "\" style=\"width: " + cellW + "px; cursor: pointer;\"  onclick=\"DagOpenFlyout('cell" + i + "', " + i + ")\">\n"
```

Here is an implementation of the function:

```
function DagOpenFlyout(elt, tbItemIndex)
{   
    parent.parent.mapFrame.OpenFlyout(500, tbItemIndex);
}
```

On the `DagOpenFlyout` function I need to pass `event` argument and in `DagOpenFlyout`  function I need to access client.X and client.Y the properties of the event argument.

How do I pass `event` argument to `DagOpenFlyout` function?

Comment: `if (window.event) event; // This`

Comment: Exactly how  you pass any other argument: `DagOpenFlyout(event, ....)`.

Comment: @FelixKling  onclick=\"DagOpenFlyout('cell" + i + "', " + i + ", " + event + ")\"  I try this. to sent event argument. But it seems to be wrong.

Comment: `onclick=\"DagOpenFlyout('cell" + i + "', " + i + ", event)\"` . `event` is a variable inside the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Close the `DagOpenFlyout` function over the `onClick` handler.

```
function DagOpenFlyout(elt, tbItemIndex) {
    return function(event) {
        // You can access event argument here in the onClick handler.
    };
}
```